# Knowing when datalist is currently active/open

Tags: html-datalist

Is it possible to know when the HTML `<datalist>` is currently active/open (via css pseudo-element or javascript event or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onfocus` and `onfocusout` event handlers of the associated input tag. `onfocusout` will not fire of you select one of the datalist options because the input tag will still have focus. You can add the `onchange` event handler for this.

```html
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" onfocus="console.log ('active');" onfocusout="console.log ('inactive');" oninput="console.log ('inactive')" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
  <option value="Chocolate"></option>
  <option value="Coconut"></option>
  <option value="Mint"></option>
  <option value="Strawberry"></option>
  <option value="Vanilla"></option>
</datalist>
```

This is not a perfect solution since it does not work when you select the same value twice.

Comment: Thanks! However, in my case I don't think this will work, since I start with a focussed input field and while someone is typing, most likely search suggestions show up. So I want to check if the user has selected one of these suggestions so I can immediately perform a search on input (which I don't want to do otherwise, since the user might want to keep typing for a longer search term...

Comment: Perhaps it would even make sense for a new event to be specified in a newer ecma script version on the input field for this?